# Javascript: this.value Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

Ok so I have the following function:

```
function hideValue(value) {
    if (this.value == value) {
       this.value = '';
}
```

And the following form field:

```
<input onfocus="hideValue('First Name')" type="text" name="first_name" value="First Name">
```

I cannot get the function to hide the value. When I `alert(value);` in the function, it returns the correct value.

I also have a showValue function which does the opposite. Why are these not working?

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the element when you call the function that way (so `this.value` is likely undefined).

Comment: Note, you're missing a closing bracket which will give you a syntax error. Answerers should be aware of this in their responses.

Comment: Woops that was my bad. It's in my code but not in the post. Thanks to everyone who responded, makes sense now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an event handler on a DOM element `this` refers to the element only in the first level of the function. Therefore you need to pass `this` into the function:

```
<input
  onfocus="hideValue(this,'First Name') /* 'this' is only correct here */"
  type="text" name="first_name" value="First Name"
>
```

The function should therefore be modified to:

```
function hideValue(element, value) {
  if (element.value == value) {
    element.value = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to this over using placeholder? Or is placeholder a better practice?

Comment: @TimothyFisher `placeholder` is the best way to do this kind of functionality, unless you want to support granny's generation browsers.

Comment: Thanks Tushar! I marked this as the solution as it was the first I saw that made the function work. The placeholder suggestion I will probably go with though!

Comment: @TimothyFisher No prob. I'm happy you'll use `placeholder` :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend to use [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) for this kind of functionality.

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[**Browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder)

**Demo:**

```html
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
```

---

**Problem:**

`this` inside the function `hideValue()` refers to the Global `window` object.

**Solution:**

You can pass `this` reference to the event handler.

```
<input onfocus="hideValue(this, 'First Name')"
                          ^^^^
```

And catch that inside event handler

```
function hideValue(that, value) {
                   ^^^^           // What is that? `this`
    if (that.value === value) {
        that.value = '';
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4q9n0L6w/1/)

```js
function hideValue(that, value) {
    if (that.value === value) {
        that.value = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<input onfocus="hideValue(this, 'First Name')" type="text" name="first_name" value="First Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onfocus="hideValue(this,'First Name')" type="text" name="first_name" value="First Name">

<script>

    function hideValue(thisvalue,value) {

    if (thisvalue.value == value) {
       thisvalue.value = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please check this. Its working fine